# Ubuntu 19.04 Icons mount disk to dock

Tags: dash-to-dock

Goodmorning, I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 and I don't see icon disk mounted on the dock (in Ubuntu 19.10 I saw it). It's possible add it?

Thank you

Comment: try `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts true`

Comment: I tried but show me this message "show-mounts" nonexistent

Comment: `df -H` will list disk mounts

Comment: `gnome-tweaks` can be used to activate mounted volume icons which display on the desktop. Tweaks >> Desktop >> Mounted Volumes

Answer (score 1):

`File system     Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
udev            4,2G     0    4,2G   0% /dev
tmpfs           831M  2,1M    829M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       487G  7,8G    455G   2% /
tmpfs           4,2G   79M    4,1G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,3M  4,1k    5,3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4,2G     0    4,2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      4,4M  4,4M       0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop0      4,0M  4,0M       0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/107
/dev/loop2       47M   47M       0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop3       16M   16M       0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/254
/dev/loop4      4,5M  4,5M       0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop5      1,1M  1,1M       0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop6      4,0M  4,0M       0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/77
/dev/loop7       16M   16M       0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/359
/dev/loop8       94M   94M       0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop9       58M   58M       0 100% /snap/core18/1223
/dev/loop10      38M   38M       0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop11      57M   57M       0 100% /snap/core18/941
/dev/loop12     159M  159M       0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/31
/dev/loop15     1,1M  1,1M       0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop13      94M   94M       0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop14     164M  164M       0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
tmpfs           831M   13k    831M   1% /run/user/123
tmpfs           831M   33k    831M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc1       1,1T  632G    369G  64% /media/andrea/HDD EXT AND`